# How to retrieve a data field that has wrong type in database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm writing a python script to extract data from a existing encoded database and make the data readable.

Now I want to retrieve data from the database but a data field has wrong type: it should be BLOB but actually TEXT.

UPD: I know use `ord()` can make it work but I wonder whether it's a good idea. I prefer a way to read them as BLOB.

```
import sqlite3
dbName = 'db'
def decode(data):
  key = b'111111111111'
  n = len(data)
  ret = bytearray(n)
  for i in range(0, n):
    ret[i] = data[i]^key[i%len(key)]
  return ret.decode('utf-8')

db = sqlite3.connect(dbName)
cur = db.cursor()
print(dbName + ' connected')

with open('friends', 'r') as f:
  for friend in f:
    ret = cur.execute('select frienduin from ' + friend)
    for row in ret:
      frienduin = decode(row[0])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sqlsol.py", line 23, in <module>
    frienduin = decode(row[0])
  File "sqlsol.py", line 10, in decode
    ret[i] = data[i]^key[i%len(key)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is of type `str`, perhaps trying

```
ret[i] = int(data[i]) ^ key[i%n]
```

might work.

Comment: int('#') leads to a error. You may refer to ord(). But it's still not a good solution. Because there are mixed TEXT and BLOB.  I prefer a way to read them as BLOB

Comment: Read them as BLOB means the Python datatype should be `bytes` instead of `str`, right?

Comment: Yes, it should be.